# POST request without mime type is not triggering the endpoint method

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey

I have an API that I am NOT allowed to change:

```
@POST
@Path("/accomodation/{area}/{val1}/{val2}")
Response createAccomEntry(@PathParam("area") String area, @PathParam("val1") String val1, @PathParam("val2") String val2);
```

I can only change the implementation:

```
@Override
public Response createAccomEntry(@PathParam("area") String area, @PathParam("val1") String val1, @PathParam("val2") String val2) {
    //can't debug the code here
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

The creators of the API did not specify any mime type to be consumed etc. and I am unable to debug it at the moment. From my REST client I make a POST request to http://localhost:8080/accomodation/area/val1/val2 I set "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as the Content-Type header and in the payload I give it like:

```
area=mock&val1=mock&val2=mock
```

But all I get is 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because once you add *any* JAX-RS annotations on the *implementation*, it negates *all* JAX-RS annotations on the corresponding interface method. This is how the spec is designed. So when you use `@PathParam`, that alone will negate all the other annotations on the interface method, including the `@POST` and the `@Path`, which is what is need to register that endpoint with Jersey. So just remove all the `@PathParam`s on the implementation, and it should work.

Comment: whew, it really did!

Comment: but it's strange that some of the already implemented methods just work that way with @PathParams...

Comment: If you want to add annotations on the implementation method, then you need to add _all_ of them.